# AngularJS Routing and ng-view issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Hey everyone I am trying to work through a tutorial for Angularjs, and am stuck on some routing issues.

It seams like the route is actually working but no content is showing up in my  section.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body >
<div>
    <!-- Placeholder for views -->
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
                })

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });

    function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
            { name: 'Blake', city: 'Redding' },
            { name: 'Nico', city: 'Portland' },
            { name: 'Simoneg', city: 'Bakersfield' },
            { name: 'Kyle', city: 'Washougal' }
        ];          
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot guys, I looked in my console and first found the bad link, I then found out that I could not do this without setting up a localhost for the project. I installed xampp used this tutorial to do it. http://www.textpattern.net/wiki/index.php?title=using_xampp_(apache-mysql-php-perl)_for_windows#VirtualHost_Containers_.28Optional.29

Comment: i guess you are following 60min angular js video..;) same thing was happening to me..i include following js from url <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script> and it started working

Comment: check your dev tools console.. your angular code is correct.

Comment: If the angular-route script (it was made into a separate module from 1.2 IIRC) is missing there should be an error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys, I looked in my console and first found the bad link, I then found out that I could not do this without setting up a localhost for the project. I installed xampp used this tutorial to do it. http://www.textpattern.net/wiki/index.php?title=using_xampp_(apache-mysql-php-perl)_for_windows#VirtualHost_Containers_.28Optional.29